# Setting up Amazon SP-API Notification API

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-selling-partner-api

Trying to set up Amazon SP-API Notifications Api but I am running into a few issues

I have setup everything up to creating a destination and subscription for SQS. After completing that part, I am now stuck on how to get the information to a specific endpoint that I want. I also cant seem to figure out how will I pass in MFN_ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE to get all the necessary information from the SQS.

Comment: How in the world did you create a destination? No matter what I do I get an "invalid signature" response from Amazon!

Comment: I had to use postman. So in order to create a destination you need to pass in two tokens. Creating a destination is a grantless operation so you need to pass two tokens. You need to pass in the toke for grantless and the stsToken after then creat the destination.   Hopefully this helps https://www.postman.com/restless-capsule-266764/workspace/amazon-spapi/request/14782630-1365ae4c-818d-4e20-9028-940fc7d273d0

Comment: The sts token is called after the token for grantless. The process goes like this. Grantless token => sts token=> then create destination.. grab the destination ID. After that you need a the original token=> sts token=> create subscription. Then ur done. I can elaborate more butthat would be on Monday so if your still stuck add a comment here on Monday and I will reach out because their documentation is crap and I understand the pain. Took me weeks to figure it out but once it's setup it's a breeze @ToddT

Comment: take a look at what I put in the answer when you have a minute. Like I say in the post below I am only having issues with the final request. I can even use the LWA and STS creds in postman and it works fine.. So it has to be something with that final request. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToddT, They mention in docs https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/notifications-api-v1-use-case-guide#step-2-create-a-destination

> Calling the createDestination operation does not require authorization from any selling partner. In this respect, this operation is a "grantless" operation and has a different authorization model from most other Selling Partner API operations.

```
POST https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/notifications/v1/destinations
{
  "name": "YourDestinationName",
  "resourceSpecification":
  {
    "sqs":
    {
      "arn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:444455556666:queue1"
    }
  }
}
```

https://developer-docs.amazon.com/amazon-shipping/docs/grantless-operations

Answer (score 0):

Amr,
Hey, I'm putting this here so you can see my code and maybe see what I'm doing wrong. As I can use postman like a champ. And the API works just fine, but when I translate to my own code it fails every time, and I have no idea why..

Here goes. I'll just put in everything here

```
module CreateSqsSubscriptionService
  module_function
  require 'faraday_middleware/aws_sigv4'

  def call
    @destination_url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/notifications/v1/destinations"
    @body = {
      "name": "Todd",
      "resourceSpecification": {
        "sqs": {
          "arn": "arn of the queue I'm setting up"
        }
      }
    }
    get_lwa_access_token
    request_temp_keys
    create_destination
  end
```

I can get the LWA access token just fine like this:

```
  def get_lwa_access_token
    response = Typhoeus.post("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token", body: {
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: "lwa id for the app",
      client_secret: "lwa secret for the app",
      scope: "sellingpartnerapi::notifications"
    })
    @access_token = JSON.parse(response.body)["access_token"]
  end
```

Then these temp keys are great too

```
def request_temp_keys
sts_client = Aws::STS::Client.new(
  region: "us-east-1",
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new("ID", "secret")
)

@temp_credentials = sts_client.assume_role({
  role_arn: "arn for SellerAPIRole set in IAM",
  role_session_name: "SPSession"
}).to_h[:credentials]

@temp_credentials #this includes the [:access_key_id] [:secret_access_key] AND [:session_token]
end
```

Ok, all good to this point. But this is where it fails:

```
  def create_destination

    conn = Faraday.new(url: 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com') do |faraday|
    faraday.request :aws_sigv4,
            credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(@temp_credentials[:access_key_id], @temp_credentials[:secret_access_key], @temp_credentials[:session_token]),
            service: 'execute-api',
            region: 'us-east-1'
    faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  end

  response = conn.post('/notifications/v1/destinations') do |req|
      req.headers["x-amz-access-token"] = @access_token
      req.body = @body.to_json
  end

  pp response
 end
```

Yea all I ever get is "Access token is missing in the request header"

But of course when I look at the request, its definitely NOT missing.. Love it!